# Can't convert D3 to use local data instead of remote

Tags: json, d3.js, local

I've got a page working nicely using remote data [here](http://researchdata.co.uk/d3/tree/).

This uses the following code to load the JSON:

```
treeJSON = d3.json("./data/data.json", function(error, treeData) {
   ...
   // Append a group which holds all nodes and which the zoom Listener can act upon.
   var svgGroup = baseSvg.append("g");

   // Define the root
   root = treeData;
   root.x0 = viewerHeight / 2;
   root.y0 = 0-(viewerWidth / 2) + 50;

   // Layout the tree initially and center on the root node.
   collapse(root);
   update(root);
   centerNode(root);
});
```

Following info online I have changed the first line to:

```
var myJSON = '{"name":"All patients","size":100,"colour":"#70AD47","children":[{"name":"Operable","size":33,"colour":"#C55A11","children":[{"name":"Stage IV","size":28,"children":[{"name":"Debulking: None","size":14},{"name":"Debulking: ≤1","size":8},{"name":"Debulking: > 1","size":6}]},{"name":"Stage IIIb/c","size":5,"children":[{"name":"Debulking: None","size":2},{"name":"Debulking: ≤1","size":1},{"name":"Debulking: > 1","size":2}]}]},{"name":"Potentially operable","size":44,"colour":"#1F4E79","children":[{"name":"Stage IV","size":36,"children":[{"name":"Becoming inoperable","size":5},{"name":"Debulking: None","size":12},{"name":"Debulking: ≤1","size":11},{"name":"Debulking: > 1","size":8}]},{"name":"Stage IIIb/c","size":8,"children":[{"name":"Becoming inoperable","size":2},{"name":"Debulking: None","size":2},{"name":"Debulking: ≤1","size":2},{"name":"Debulking: > 1","size":2}]}]},{"name":"Inoperable","size":23,"colour":"#7F7F7F","children":[{"name":"Stage IV","size":16},{"name":"Stage IIIb/c","size":7}]}]}';
var treeData = JSON.parse(myJSON);
```

I have also removed the last line.

My problem is that nothing at all is appearing on screen. console logging shows that the treeData object is correctly created.

I'm at a loss and would really appreciate any help that could be offered!

The code is quite long so don't think it appropriate to post here, but if anyone wouldn't mind seeing if they can work out the problem the files can be downloaded [here](http://researchdata.co.uk/d3/bubbles.zip) This contains both versions - working remote data (tree folder) and broken local data broken (localtree folder)

Would be very grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably caused by the fact that your `bubbles.js` is run before the page has been rendered. Your script can't find `#tree-container`. Putting your

```
<script src="bubbles.js"></script>
```

At the bottom of the body will solve this.